# Adding lambda functions to a symbol table of a class

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to add a lambda function to the symbol table of a class:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        func = lambda self, x: x*x  # <-- Adding 'self' produces error
        self.__dict__['test1'] = func
        print(self.test1(2))
        print(self.test2(2))

    def test2(self, b):
        return b*b*b

b = B()
```

but this produces an error (running the script with `python t.py`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./t.py", line 14, in <module>
    b = B()
  File "./t.py", line 8, in __init__
    print(self.test1(2))
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

However, if I remove `self` as an argument to the Lambda function, it works fine.

Why isn't `self` required as an argument for the Lambda function here?

Comment: You may use `self.test1 = types.MethodType(func, self)`, otherwise it will acts like a static method, without Python applying the bit of magic necessary for `self` to refer to the class instance.

Comment: @Delgan Thanks, that should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class methods' calls:

```
instance.method(arg1, arg2, ..., argn)
```

are internally binded to:

```
instance_class.method(instance, arg1, ..., argn)
```

where, obviously, `instance` is  `self`.

You are storing your lambda as an instance attribute, which wouldn't be treated like an instance method. That's why `self` is not passed automatically as first argument.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This makes sense. So adding the lambda function as an instance attribute does not make it an instance method? But how could one make the lambda be treated as an instance method?

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance) explains it very well. 
Try `self.__dict__['test1'] = types.MethodType( func, self )`

Comment: Thanks @IlarioPierbattista. I think I found a solution: according to the answer you referred to, I should be able to make it an instance method using: `self.__dict__['test1'] = types.MethodType( func, self )`

Answer (score 1):

`lambda` functions are anonymous functions, they are not bound to the class, so in this case you are creating a lambda with 2 arguments (`self` and `x`). The error is clearly telling you that when you call the lambda function you are just passing one argument bound to `self`, so you lack the `x`.